# Can't assign object to array dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, undefined, google-geocoder

I was trying to get **lat** and **lng** from the geocode and want to assign those info as object to an array `info=[]`. The code I am using is

```
var info = [];
var lat;
var lng;
$.each($('.udc-search-table tbody tr'), function(index, value) {
    var address = '.....';
    var geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocode.geocode({address: address}, function(result, status) {
        if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
            info.push({'lat' : lat});
        }
    });
    console.log(lat); // undefined and why here it is undefined
});
console.log(info); // here it is working 
// [{lat : .....}, {lat : ....}] working
```

Also when I am using this **variable** `info` to ajax data, from the server response it is just showing empty **array** as `string 2 "[]"`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: udc.ajax_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action  : 'udc_update_latlng',
        latlng : JSON.stringify(info)
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // server response string 2 "[]"
    }
});
```

But when I am assigning the object to `info` variable like this ajax server response is correct. I mean json string data is being sent.

```
$.each($('.udc-search-table tbody tr'), function(index, value) {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    info.push({'id' : ID});
});
```

Actually I need to assign the **lat** and **lng** to `info` variable to do my tasks. What is the actual problem?

Comment: `geocode()` is **asynchronous**

Comment: Yes, it is asynchronous. So how can I get the problem solved?

Comment: Create array of promises that each resolve with geocode data. Use Promise.all() on that promise array to send ajax.

Comment: I am quite good at Promise.all() stuffs. Can you please give some code example or my task related solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try the full code below

    var info = [];
    var lat;
    var lng;
    var count = 5; //total row count
    var i = 1;
    $.each($('.udc-search-table tbody tr'), function (index, value) {
        var address = '.....';
        var geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocode.geocode({address: address}, function (result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
                info.push({'lat': lat});
                if (count === i) {
                    var data = JSON.stringify(info);
                    ajaxFuntion(data);
                }
                i++;
            }
        });
    });
    function ajaxFuntion(info) {
        $.ajax({
            url: udc.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'udc_update_latlng',
                latlng: info
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```